# Siblings relationship between same models in Vapor

Tags: swift, relationship, vapor

I have a `User` model which I want to add a `friends` property to. Friends, are supposed to be other `User`s.

I created the `UserFriendsPivot`:

```
final class UserFriendsPivot: MySQLPivot, ModifiablePivot {
    var id: Int?
    var userID: User.ID
    var friendID: User.ID

    typealias Left = User
    typealias Right = User

    static var leftIDKey: WritableKeyPath<UserFriendsPivot, Int> {
        return \.userID
    }

    static var rightIDKey: WritableKeyPath<UserFriendsPivot, Int> {
        return \.friendID
    }

    init(_ user: User, _ friend: User) throws {
        self.userID   = try user  .requireID()
        self.friendID = try friend.requireID()
    }
}

extension UserFriendsPivot: Migration {
    public static var entity: String {
        return "user_friends"
    }
}
```

I added the `friends` property to `User`:

```
var friends: Siblings<User, User, UserFriendsPivot> {
    return siblings()
}
```

Now, I'm seeing the following error on the line with `return siblings()`:

> Ambiguous use of 'siblings(related:through:)'

I tried to replace it with:

```
return siblings(related: User.self, through: UserFriendsPivot.self)
```

...without any luck.

I know that the two code snippets *should* work, because I straight-up copied them from another siblings relationship I built between `Event` and `User` that is working just fine.
The only difference I'm seeing is that I'm trying to build a relationship between the same models.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that in a same-`Model` (`User-User`) siblings relation, Fluent cannot infer which sibling you are referring to – the sides need to be specified.

```
extension User {
    // friends of this user
    var friends: Siblings<User, User, UserFriendsPivot> {
        siblings(UserFriendsPivot.leftIDKey, UserFriendsPivot.rightIDKey)
    }

    // users who are friends with this user
    var friendOf: Siblings<User, User, UserFriendsPivot> {
        siblings(UserFriendsPivot.rightIDKey, UserFriendsPivot.leftIDKey)
    }
}
```

The other same-`Model` consequence is that you will not be able to use the attach convenience method to add to the pivot table, and need to manually create instead:

```
let pivot = try UserFriendsPivot(user, friend)
pivot.save(on: req)
```

(There are other approaches to work around this, I just find these straightforward ways above the easiest to use. Specifying the sides and reversing the key positions to obtain the inverse relation are the important concepts.)

---

<sup>as answered by [grundoon](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/issues/1932#issuecomment-473773815)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your `friends` definition with something like:

```
var friends: Siblings<User,UserFriendsPivot.Right, UserFriendsPivot> {
    return User.siblings()
}
```

EDIT:

It ought to work with `Left` and `Right` as the same table, but seems to fail because the aliases resolve to the base values. I.e. autocomplete in Xcode shows all the candidates for `siblings` all end up being of type:

```
Siblings<User, User, UserFriendsPivot> siblings(...)
```

Instead of:

```
Siblings<User, UserFriendsPivot.Right, UserFriendsPivot> siblings(...)
```

and similar.

I'd suggest raising a bug on GitHub. In the meantime, how about creating a copy of `User` with a different name and setting:

```
static let entity = "User"
```

to use the same physical table. Not pretty, but it might get you working.

Comment: So what should the implementation of `siblings { get }` in `User` be? Also, `Siblings<User, Right, ...>` throws the error *Use of undeclared type 'Right'*.

Comment: Move the typealias of Right to make it global scope.

Comment: Oh but then `Right` will always be `User`... I'll do `UserFriendsPivot.Right` instead. And how about `siblings`' implementation?

Comment: Have you tried (assuming siblings call is in User) trying siblings(related:UserFriendsPivot.Right, through:UserFriendsPivot)?

Comment: Only gives me *Ambiguous use of 'siblings(related:through:)'*... @Nick

Comment: Yeah I've already considered creating a `Friend` model that basically only has an id and a `userID`. Not pretty, though, like you said...

Comment: I have a change planned for one of my apps that will need this to work also! Good luck.

Comment: Was able to fix this thanks to [grundoon](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/issues/1932#issuecomment-473773815)