# Ambiguous column name when joining tables with FluentSQLite

Tags: swift, fluent, vapor, fluentsqlite

I am trying to write a route that returns all the posts written by users who are followed by a particular user. This is the data model that I'm using:

```
struct Follow: Content, SQLiteModel, Migration {
    var id: Int?
    var follower: String
    var following: String
}

struct Post: Content, SQLiteModel, Migration {
    var id: Int?
    var username: String
    var message: String
}

struct User: Content, SQLiteStringModel, Migration {
    var id: String?
    var password: String
}
```

And this is the route:

```
router.get(String.parameter, "timeline") { req -> Future<[Post]> in
    let username = try req.parameters.next(String.self)

    return Follow.query(on: req).filter(\Follow.follower == username).join(\Follow.following, to: \Post.username).alsoDecode(Post.self).all().map { tuples in
        return tuples.map { tuple in
            return tuple.1
        }
    }
}
```

The code compiles, but at runtime I get this JSON error dictionary:

```
{"error":true,"reason":"ambiguous column name: main.Follow.id"}
```

And I also have an idea that the problem is that since I am making a join, then there is a duplicate id field (Follow.id, Post.id), but how to solve this problem? in sql I would just specify something like 'as followId' in order to rename the field, but how to do this in FluentSQLite?

**Update**

This is how I modified the "timeline" route in the end:

```
return User.find(username, on: req).flatMap { user in
    guard let user = user else {
        throw Abort(.notFound)
    }

    return try user.followers.query(on: req)
        .join(\Post.username, to:\FollowUp.following)
        .alsoDecode(Post.self).all()
        .flatMap { tuples in
        return tuples.map { tuple in
            return tuple.1
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error: "Cannot convert value of type '[Post]' to closure result type 'EventLoopFuture<[Post]>'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Follow` is essentially a `Pivot` table and formally implementing it as one should get rid of your problem. However, you can run into difficulty, See:

[Siblings relationship between same models in Vapor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201301/siblings-relationship-between-same-models-in-vapor)

So, in your case, make your `follower` and `following` fields into `User.ID` type and add the following to your `Follow` model:

```
struct Follow: Content, Pivot, Migration
{
    static var idKey: WritableKeyPath<FollowUp, Int?> = .id
    typealias Database = SQLiteDatabase
    typealias ID = Int
    var id:Int?
    var follower:User.ID
    var following:User.ID

    typealias Left = User
    typealias Right = User

    static var leftIDKey: WritableKeyPath<Follow, Int> {
        return \.follower
    }

    static var rightIDKey: WritableKeyPath<Follow, Int> {
        return \.following
    }
}
```

And then create this extension:

```
extension User:
{
    var followers: Siblings<User, User, Follow> {
    return siblings(Follow.leftIDKey, Follow.rightIDKey)
    }
}
```

So, finally, your query becomes:

```
return User.find(username, on: req).flatMap { user in
    guard let user = user else {
        throw Abort(.notFound)
    }

    return try user.followers.query(on: req)
        .join(\Post.username, to:\FollowUp.following)
        .alsoDecode(Post.self).all()
        .map { tuples in
        return tuples.map { tuple in
            return tuple.1
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to tweak `Post` to hold the `User.ID` rather than `username` to make the join work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to do what you proposed, but apparently changing the Follow class from SQLiteStringModel to Pivot makes vapor unable to figure out to which database it belongs. I have some errors, like for example 'Reference to member 'sqlite' cannot be resolved without a contextual type'. And also, consider that for a user the id and the username are the same thing, given that the id is mapped to a unique string.

Comment: The real project is a bit different: I am using the struct 'FollowUp' instead of 'Follow', but they are the same. I uploaded the project on github in case you want to give it a look, you can check the last commit to the master to see how I made your proposed changes: https://github.com/ralzuhouri/project7.git